# Persistent UIToolbar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitoolbar

I've been searching for an answer to this question and found a few answers for doing something similar in Obj-C, adding the toolbar to the appdelegate and so forth, but I was wondering if there was a better to do this in Swift so that the toolbar displays across all the VCs. A Swift version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072080/persistent-uibarbuttonitem-in-uitoolbar), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668636/uitoolbar-in-rootviewcontroller) for example. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071831/uitoolbar-in-appdelegate) question but no one has offered any answers so does that mean there's no better way in Swift? I haven't used toolbars much and I'm not experienced enough with Swift to know when something simply is or is not possible. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController`s feature an optional `UIToolbar`. Simply unhide it at the start of your first view controller (in `viewDidLoad` for example) to have it display throughout your app, ex:

```
navigationController.toolbarHidden = false
```

You can subsequently set your toolbar's items within each view controller by adding items to the view controller's `toolbarItems` property:

```
toolbarItems = itemsArray
```

Comment: Thanks, @LyndseyScott. I'm getting close but I have a quick question. Where are you declaring your itemsArray to make it accessible from the other VC's? To get mine to work I had to make it global and that seems like a bad idea. That's not right, is it?

Comment: @judoTRON Oh, the itemsArray. (Sorry answered a second ago thinking you you meant toolbarItems).  With Swift all class variables are global anyway so you can have it as a class variable anywhere in your app and access it from anywhere else... It's fine it itemsArray is global in that sense.

Comment: Ok, that got it, @LyndseyScott. Thank you very much for your help. Can't upvote you but marked it as answered.